# Using Raspberry PI 4 B Wifi with 2 IP Addresses

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, dhcpcd

I need to setup my RPI 4 to use Wi-Fi but with 2 IP addresses, one from DHCP and the other one static, can someone please help I am not sure how to do this, as I need to put this configuration in the `DHCPCD.conf` file, we are not use the network manager in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Why? This is not technically impossible but not using dhcpcd and frankly there is no point.

Comment: OK for us, we need it. In the Hospitality Industry you will get info from one vlan while other vlan provide internet access. so if not possible via dhcpcd then how?

Comment: of course it's possible - it's fiddly with dhcpcd though (at least it used to be about 3 years ago) - best to switch to using NetworkManager - then it's really simple

Comment: Please explain how I must do it, so the Pi must still pickup a wifi ip from DHCP then also have the other static ip configured?

Comment: I have tried leaving the ipv4 ip setup blank, and then just added a router ip for extra ip but it does not work

Comment: done b4 with multiple static.  never with dhcp plus static, but indeed theoretically possible so I'll certainly look forward to an answer, preferably one without a virtual network adapter.

Comment: It may be easier to assign two IP addresses to two devices. For example, one to the WiFi adapter and another to the Ethernet adapter.

Comment: yes, but they dont have ethernet at the location, if I assign 2 static ip's on wifi, do I add them in the same place in network manager or must the 2nd ip be somewhere els?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set multiple static ip in dhcpcd.conf - Raspbian 8 (jessie)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45330/set-multiple-static-ip-in-dhcpcd-conf-raspbian-8-jessie)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set multiple static ip in dhcpcd.conf - Raspbian 8 (jessie)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45330/set-multiple-static-ip-in-dhcpcd-conf-raspbian-8-jessie)

Answer (score 1):

To make a Raspberry Pi wireless bridge you will need a USB WiFi adapter. Check out the following links to see if these will help you build what you are looking for.

- [Configuring a Raspberry Pi as a bridge? (purpose: extending WIFI)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106084/configuring-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-bridge-purpose-extending-wifi)
- [Raspberry Pi Ethernet to Wifi Bridge](https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-Ethernet-to-Wifi-Bridge/)

I haven't tested these myself so suggest building a wired Ethernet to WiFi Ethernet bridge using eth0 and wlan0 on the raspberry Pi. If that works then upgrade by adding a USB wireless adapter, and change eht0 to wlan1 or what ever the wireless adapter appears as.